# How to update pre-existing dependency when using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `create-react-app` for a project. I installed various eslint plugins etc, however, we all know that create-react-app already comes with certain dependencies that are not shown in `package.json`.

I want the newest `eslint` version which is currently 5.3.0. Create-react-app comes with 5.16.0. WITHOUT EJECTING, how do I bring this dependency to the newest version without breaking everything?

I get the following error:

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "^5.16.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

:\node_modules\eslint (version: 5.3.0)
```

Comment: 16 is larger than 3... I created an app with CRA a day or two ago and it's using ESLint 5.16.0, which NPM says is the newest version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint

Comment: Did U solve this? I have this issue too and below answers don't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Things in package.json will take precedence so if you upgrade version of `eslint`, `react-scripts` should always take the latest version.

There is a small loophole though. If you fiddle too much with dependencies you might get the warning about mismatch version by `react-scripts`. To avoid that you can create `.env` file and can specify the following.

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

Comment: I added the error description to the post. I searched for anything 5.3.0 and none are related to eslint. Not sure where it's pulling that version from, but I also don't fully want to disable this otherwise useful warning message

Comment: The latest version of eslint is `5.16.0` while in package.json you have mentioned `5.3.0`. Create react scripts have its own dependencies which is just verifying that in its config 5.16.0 is given while in your node_modules 5.3.0 is installed. To skip the error create .env file and add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to downgrade the eslint version to 5.3.0

Comment: as I mentioned, 5.3 is not mentioned anywhere in the project files, to include files in the node-modules folder as well as package/-lock.json etc

Comment: can you try removing node_modules folder and doing `npm install`? looks like somehow your local node_modules have 5.3.0 most probably from last `npm install` command execution.

Comment: I've done that, according to the create-react-app error-message notification. Removed `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and uninstalled `eslint` from `package.json`, then `npm install`. Didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this issue, the error says:
`The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
"eslint": "5.16.0"`

but also says you have another version at package.json that's 
`\node_modules\eslint (version: 5.3.0)` in my case was 6.1.0

so my solution was: 
I searched for the dependency called eslint and updated the version similar to Create React App expected `"eslint": "^5.16.0"` at package.json
Then run `npm install` and now you can run npm start... if you have troubles with `slint-plugin-import` just update the version as well.